# Passing a method as callback

Tags: javascript, oop, callback

I am trying to pass a method as a callback reference to a method of another class:

```
function A() {
    this.callback = function(){return 0;};
}

A.prototype.set = function(cb) {
    this.callback = cb;
};

A.prototype.test = function(){
    console.log("test " + this.callback());
};

function B(o) {
    this.prop = "blah B";
    o.set(this.blah);
}

B.prototype.blah = function() {
    console.log(this);
    return this.prop;
};
```

What I would expect from the execution

```
a = new A();
b = new B(a);
a.test();
```

is the result

```
>B { prop="blah B", blah=function()}
>test blah B
```

But instead the console shows

```
>A { cb=function(), set=function(), test=function()}
>test undefined
```

as if the method `blah` has been assigned to `A` for the execution..

Why am I getting this result?
And how can I get the result I expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"as if the method blah has been assigned to A for the execution", you almost got it, just replace "A" with "a" in your sentence. Indeed, by default, `this` refers to the *instance* which owns the method.

As it happens, `o.set(this.blah)` can be translated into `a.callback = b.blah`, which means that `a.callback` and `b.blah` now refer to the same function. In other words, the same function is now owned by both instances `a` and `b` :

```
a.callback() // "return (this -> a).prop" -> undefined
b.blah()     // "return (this -> b).prop" -> "blah B"
```

Roughly speaking, you need a way to "redirect" `this` to `b` inside `callback`.

You could use either a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) :

```
var me = this;
o.set(function () {
    // this -> a
    // me   -> b
    return me.blah();
});
```

Or [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) ([not supported by IE8 and below](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/)) :

```
o.set(this.blah.bind(this));
```

Comment: The closure method doesn't work, it needs to be `function(){return me.blah();}` (as `blah` returns a value). I didn't know `bind`, it's an interesting one.. And it doesn't really matter for the IE compatibility, the rest of my code isn't compatible <IE8 anyway...

Comment: @ThierryJ. Thanks for your reply, I've fixed the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is how JavaScript's `this` keyword works - it refers to the current execution context, which is the object it is called on in this case. You are calling it as if it was a method of `A`. You need to call it as a method on your `B` instance. If you don't need to support IE8 or lower, you can use [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to bind `this` in the function so it always points to the `B` instance. Otherwise, the `A` instance needs a reference to the `B` instance on which to call the method.

You could manually bind the method with a `var self = this;` hack. You could also do this in the `B` constructor:

```
function B(o) {
    var self = this;
    this.prop = "blah B";
    o.set(function() { self.blah(); });
}
```

But if you could expand a bit on what exactly you're trying to do, there might be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because of execution context - how `this` of a function in JavaScript is bound to. When the final line `a.test()` is called, the `callback` looks for a property called `prop` in the context of the object `a`. In your case, the object `a` did not have a `prop` property and hence the `undefined`.  When you supply a `prop` to `a` then it works fine. Final fiddle with `console.log` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u9p4D/2/). Here the callback is called twice, once without the assignment of `prop` and the second with the assignment of the same:

```
function B(o) {
    this.prop = "blah B";
    o.set(this.blah);
    o.prop = this.prop;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When `blah` method is called inside the `test` method, `this` points to an `A` instance. Since `A` does not have a `prop` property it returns undefined.

You need to change the line `o.set(this.blah);` to this `o.set(this.blah.bind(this));`

Now `blah` is always bound to an instance of `B` and when `test` is called `this.prop` will return `"blah B"` which is what is intended.